# How to make a square video 1:1 without losing its aspect ration in Flutter with video_player package

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

Trying to crop the video of a video to display a preview as a square without changing its width and height.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it makes a square video

```
Container(
  width: 200, //Crop width
  height: 200, //Crop height
  child: FittedBox(
    // alignment: Alignment.center, //Move around the crop
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: videoController.value.size.width,
      height: videoController.value.size.height,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: videoController.value.aspectRatio,
        child: VideoPlayer(
          videoController,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: You can use the "AspectRatio" widget and use "aspectRatio: 1" and doesn't matter the size of the screen, it will always be square.